# Delete previous data and refresh to the new one

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to create a table2 from another table1. I want to add a sub code that would let me delete the data in the table2, refresh the data overall and then continue to create the new table2 based on the refreshed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
`Range("A:D").clearcontents` in your code to clear columns

I assumed your range is column A:D